# Cube css3 using Impress js

Tags: css, impress.js

based on the demo here 
https://github.com/bartaz/impress.js

i have tried moving from front face of the cube to the top but i am unable to rotate to the other faces..
the aim is to have some content on all the six sides of a cube and on pressing the space bar i should be able to toggle to each face

my html code which works for two face is as follows

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<link type ="text/css" href="css/customstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body> 
    <div id="impress">

    <div id="step-1" class="step slide" data-x="200" data-y="200">
        <p>
            <span class="text1">A</span> 
            <span class="text2">B</span>
            <span class="text3">C</span>

        </p>

     </div>

<div id="step-2" class="step slide"  data-x="100" data-y="145"  data-z="-1000" data-rotate-x="180" data-scale="1" >

  <p>
        Face 2 :) </p> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was waiting for someone to answer.

1 tough time consuming option is to put your text upon an image.The image would have various shades and tint of 1 color to give the 3d effect.Using z-index put your text above the image.

Another option,is to contact the developer directly.I guess he is reachable on Github.perhaps he would have better,simple,shorter ways to the required out